# Why is void used in this manner with an inline function?

Tags: c++, inline

I just ran across this in some sample code and I've never seen it used before. For an inline function which returns a type but the return value is not used, the author preceded the call with a `(void)`. Does this actually do anything?

Example:

```
inline some_object& SomeClass::doSomething();

SomeClass o;

(void)o.doSomething();
```

Comment: To squelch the source code analyzer's warning the caller is ignoring the return result.

Comment: Suppress compiler warning about ignoring the return-value of the function.

Comment: By casting to `void` it might not produce an unused value warning on some compiler set to some strict level of warning.  So maybe it's intended to get clean compiles.   Similarly, if you have a function with unused arguments (to match a signature, for instance for a QT signal), you can cast the arguments to `void` inside the function and still have a 'clean' compile with no warnings.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically done when using a tool like [Lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) which has been configured to issue a warning if you call a function and ignore its return value.

Comment: Note that it's not just lint-like tools that issue such warnings, compilers can also detect ignored function results and/or arguments, requiring casting to `void` to quiet the warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is (IMO) a horrible practice that's fostered by some tools<sup>1</sup> that give warnings about calling a function and ignoring what it returns.

The right way to deal with the problem is to give the tool a list of functions whose return values can reasonably be ignored. If the tool doesn't support that, it's probably useless and should be thrown away. In the case of a compiler, you may not be able to throw away the tool itself, and may have to settle for just globally disabling that warning.

---

<sup>1. Most often something like `lint`, but some compilers can do the same.</sup>

Comment: My comment to Sean's answer applies to your answer as well: compilers may detect this as well.

Comment: @cmaster: A compiler that's sufficiently prone to issuing meaningless warnings *is* a lint (that also happens to generate code).

Comment: I share your distaste for such chatty tools that require extra quirks on legit code to shut up. Yet, compilers like `gcc` (which I know can issue these warnings) are generally not recognized as linting tools. And you cannot stop using a compiler, you can just switch off the offending warning. As such, it would add to the understandability of your answer to add a comment on compilers.